# How to find a specific word in Iframe page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, find, cpu-word

How to find a specific word in an `iframe` page?

I don't have control over the `iframe` page so all codes must be placed in teh parent page.

This is a code to find a word in the parent page

```
init();

function init()
{
    searchWord("exgirlfriend");  
}

function searchWord(word)
{
   var pageResults = document.body.innerHTML.match(word);  
   if(pageResults)
   {
       alert("word found");    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the content of an iframe that comes from another domain because of the **same origin policy**.